# Is bowing to the audience at the end of a play shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, behavior

Bowing or prostrating to anyone other than Allah (may he be exalted and praised) is shirk but does that also include what some actors do at the end of a play?

Answer (score 2):

No, its not. What actors do at the end is a sign of gratitude. This bowing is not a bowing of submission as we do in prayers. They show that they are humbled by the appreciation from the audience. There is not even a shadow of associating partners with God in this bowing.

Answer (score 0):

Bowing or prostrating to anyone other than Allah isn't shirk unless you intended to worship the other object.  If they were worship on their own with no niyyah, you'd be worshiping the things in front of you even if you didn't want to.

Therefore, it matters on the intention.  The actor, or any performer, bowing to the audience isn't committing shirk, or even a sin, as long as they're not on the intent of worshiping the audience or believe them to be gods besides Allah.